# How do you get a UI button to do different tasks each time it is pressed?

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, xcode6

When I create an IBaction for a button I can easily get it to perform an action for example:

```
@IBAction func click(sender: AnyObject) {

label6.hidden = false}
```

How do I get it to execute a totally different task when it is clicked for a second or third time etc?

Thanks

EDIT:  When I try this I get an error "Viewcontroller.type does not have a member named "label1", this also is stated for "label2" Any ideas why as I have already added the label in as an outlet. Do I need to declare it somewhere else to get it to work? Thanks

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    label1.text = ""
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBOutlet weak var label1: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var label2: UILabel!

class MyButtonClass
{
    var clickCounter: Int = 0

    @IBAction func click(sender: AnyObject)
    {
        clickCounter += 1

        if (clickCounter == 1)
        {label1.text = "text1"}

        else if (clickCounter == 2)
        {label2.text = "text1"
        clickCounter = 0}
    }
}
```

}

Comment: can you provide more details like how to you want to excecute diff funcs ,randomly or in predefinded manner?how many func?total count etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your code with the following:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController
{
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        label1.text = ""
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var label1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var label2: UILabel!

    var clickCounter: Int = 0

    @IBAction func click(sender: AnyObject)
    {
        clickCounter += 1

        if (clickCounter == 1)
        {
            label1.text = "text1"
        }

        else if (clickCounter == 2)
        {
            label2.text = "text1"
            clickCounter = 0
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: class MyButtonClass
{
    var clickCounter: Int = 0
    
    @IBAction func button1(sender: AnyObject) {

        clickCounter += 1
            
        if (clickCounter == 1)
        {label1.hidden = true}
                
        else if (clickCounter == 2)
        {label2.hidden = true}
        clickCounter = 0}
        }
When I try this I get an error "Viewcontroller.type does not have a member named "label1", this also is stated for "label2"  Any ideas why as I have already added the label in as an outlet.  Do I need to declare it somewhere else to get it to work?  Thanks

Comment: Can you provide the code of your class where the label variables are defined? I'll be able to provide substantial help given the right material.

Comment: IBOutlet weak var label1: UILabel!
    IBOutlet weak var label2: UILabel!
    
    class MyButtonClass
    {
        var clickCounter: Int = 0
        
        @IBAction func click(sender: AnyObject)
        {
            clickCounter += 1
            
            if (clickCounter == 1)
            {label1.text = "text1"}
                
            else if (clickCounter == 2)
            {label2.text = "text1"
            clickCounter = 0}
        }
    }

Comment: I removed the @ signs from the IBOutlets at the beginning as it was thinking I was tagging people.

Comment: Edit your answer and put the code in it. Copying the entire class's code would be helpful.

Comment: I've edited my answer to fit your needs. I'd highly suggest reading Apple's Swift documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a counter and depending on its value fire another method from the one called on click

Answer (score 0):

- Create a property that counts the tap count
- Increment the tap count on each click
- Implement a switch on the tap count to perform different actions (IBAction acts as a dispatcher)